# How to deal with exception when connection lost happens to Spring WebClient

Tags: spring, netty, spring-webflux

I am using Spring WebClient to receive Server Sent Event. When my server shuts down, I got the following exception stack:

```
[reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations:283] - [HttpClient] Error processing connection. Requesting close the channel
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

[reactor-http-nio-4] [] [] [reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ContextHandler:283] - Error cannot be forwarded to user-facing Mono
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

[io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext:146] - An exception '{}' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

It is quite obvious in the deep somewhere of WebClient, the Netty caught the exception. However, my question is: how can I catch it so that I can gracefully deal with it.

My code:

```
final Flux<Object> stream = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/ssp/common/v1/eventstream")
            .build()
            .get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(ServerSentEvent.class)
            .flatMap(e -> Mono.justOrEmpty(e.data()))
            .repeat();

    stream.doOnError(e -> System.out.println(e));
    stream.subscribe(e -> processEvent(e));
```

The stream.doOnError() doesn't help for this case. With M. Deinum's comment, I modified the code:

```
final Flux<Object> stream = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/ssp/common/v1/eventstream")
            .build()
            .get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(ServerSentEvent.class)
            .flatMap(e -> Mono.justOrEmpty(e.data()))
            .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("haha"))
            .repeat();

    stream.subscribe(e -> processEvent(e));
```

Then, it is getting a bit better. I got the "haha" printed but I still got the exception stack (a bit shorter):

```
[reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations:283] - [HttpClient] Error processing connection. Requesting close the channel
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

[reactor-http-nio-4] [] [] [reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ContextHandler:283] - Error cannot be forwarded to user-facing Mono
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: Shouldn't all those calls be chained? You aren't reusing the result of the `doOnError` so I doubt it will actually be registered at all.

Comment: So the remaining part of your question is asking how to configure logging in a java application?

Comment: Yes, basically how to hide the exception.

Comment: @JohnZhang usually it's a common practice to use logback as a logger together with Spring. To ignore the error in logs just add the following line to your logback config:

`<logger name="io.netty" level="OFF">`

Comment: @SerhiiPovísenko isn't it a bit too risky disabling all the Netty errors? Ideally, the connection error should've been handled and logged without the stack-trace.

Comment: @JohnZhang were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Mr.AJ well, to be honest, I spent so much time on it and came to the conclusion that it's something related to the deep Netty implementation. You are right about login the error - for example, on sending a request you could catch the error and output it, but in our case, this connection closed messages appear in the background rather than when you call any specific thing,  thus I just disable it to avoid having that garbage in the logs. But again - you are right - it's better to fix it, but there is no fix so far. If any is there - I'm also interested to know, 'cause it's still there haha